# How can I set-up Zeppelin to be part of startup services on CentOS?

Tags: centos, apache-zeppelin

## OP Answer Below (In Hopes to Help the Community)

Below you will see my actual answer.  (I am posting this question to pass on the answer.)  It took me a while to find the proper answer, so I am posting here to potentially speed up the efforts for other poor souls.

---

## Apache Zeppelin Install Only Explains Ubuntu Case

If you look on [Apache's site](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/install/install.html) (as of Jan 2018), you'll see instructions for setting up services (e.g., daemons that you can have launch upon startup, reboot, etc.) on Ubuntu OS.  You'll find something like:

`sudo service zeppelin start

sudo service zeppelin stop

sudo service zeppelin restart`

But if you go through the standard install as per that page, there is no registered `zeppelin` service by default after following the install, when using CentOS 7. That is, if you type something like `service zeppelin start` that service won't be found.

Moreover, for CentOS 7, which is what I am using, there is a [shift towards using `systemctl` instead](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-7-systemctl-replacements-of-legacy-commands-service-and-chkconfig/). But trying `systemctl` did not work, either (`zeppelin` was not found).

---

## Zeppelin Itself Works Fine, Only Trouble with "Auto-Launch"

I can get the direct executable call, e.g., `./bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh start`, to work fine.  But that isn't providing the solution I want.  I want to be able to know that if the machine is rebooted or anything else, Zeppelin will be available because it launches at start.

Answer (score 7):

## Challenging Search

I figured the "truth must be out there", but many paths in my search were not helpful.

However, [this link from InfoWorld](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3226734/how-to-set-up-zeppelin-for-analytics-and-visualization.html) did the trick.

---

## Key Issues

In summary, there were 2 issues I needed to understand:

1. In CentOS 7, while `systemctl` is ideal, `service` is still acceptable.
2. For whatever reason, the `zeppelin.service` file is not automatically created in CentOS (and maybe all non-Ubuntu flavors of *nix?), ***even though the standard `.service` file would work fine***.  So please go ahead and read that link, but the important part for this story was that I needed to do the following:

   1. Create an `/etc/systemd/system/zeppelin.service` file from scratch.
   2. In that file, place the following:

```
Description=Service to run Zeppelin Daemon
Documentation=
[Service]
User=zeppelin
Group=zeppelin
Type=forking
WorkingDirectory=/home/zeppelin
ExecStart=/home/zeppelin/zeppelin-current/bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh start
ExecStop=/home/zeppelin/zeppelin-current/bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh stop
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

## Some Details

Most of the above is probably self-evident (and the linked article does not explain the details overly much), but here is a breakdown:

- `User=zeppelin`: in this case the Zeppelin instance was being set up as multi-user, log in from a server remotely.  If you want the auto-launch of Zeppelin upon reboot, you likely have the same use case.

  - So, you "should" create a user `zeppelin` (any generic user for the Zeppelin software to use), which is explained in the InfoWorld link, but [also here](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/security/shiroauthentication.html).
- `Group=zeppelin`: same as above.
- `WorkingDirectory`: same as above (create a user `zeppelin`, install Zeppelin there, yada, yada... the link has more info on steps).
- `ExecStart`: This is the key line; you need to ensure that whenever you type in `service zeppelin start`, it points to this path, the path you put in `ExecStart`.
- `ExecStop`: Same idea as above.

---

## Register the New Service

Then the last bit of "magic" is to type:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

This is the key bit.  It is analogous to typing `source ~/.bash_profile` if that means anything.  This is the line where you're saying, in effect, refresh all of your daemons.

Lastly, I recommend explicitly typing

```
service zeppelin start
```

so that you are sure that it is found.  Presuming it actually does something (e.g., you see something like `Zeppelin start   [  OK  ]` or else `Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start zeppelin.service`... in either case, you know that the `service` was found and worked).